# A criterion for a module over a local ring to be of finite length

Tags: modules, localization, local-rings

Let $R$ be a local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ and let $M$ be an $R$-module. For a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}\in R$, $M_p$ shall denote the localization of $M$ at $p$.

I've read the following and I can't see why it's true:

If $M_p=0$ for any prime ideal in $R$ that is distinct from $\mathfrak{m}$, then $M$ is a module of finite length.

I just know that if $M_m=0$ as well, that $M=0$.

Comment: Do you want $M$ to be finitely generated? Otherwise an infinite sum of copies of $k := R/{\mathfrak m}$ gives a counterexample.

Comment: Is your local ring noetherian?

Comment: Yes, sorry the ring is noetherian and $M$ is finitely generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* Show that for any $m\in M$, $\text{Ann}_R(m)$ is not contained in any non-maximal prime - consider what it means for $m$ to map to $0$ in $M_{\mathfrak p}$ for that. Deduce that there exists $l\gg 0$ (depending on $m$) such that ${\mathfrak m}^l m = \{0\}$ (note that $Rm\subset M$ is a module over $R/\text{Ann}_R(m)$, which is Artinian local by the first step). Finally, using finite generation of $M$ conclude that there's some $l\gg 0$ such that ${\mathfrak m}^l M = 0$, and build a finite filtration from that.

Comment: If $m$ is mapped to 0 in $M_\mathfrak{p}$, than there exists a $s\in R\setminus \mathfrak{p}$ with $ms=0$ and if $Ann_R(m)\subseteq \mathfrak{p}$ for a non-maximal prime, than $m$ would not be send to $0$ in $M_\mathfrak{p}$ so $M_\mathfrak{p}\not=0$. A contradiction. I can't see the conclusion so far....maybe I am missing a known result

Comment: @Jules I added some details - let me know if it helps.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your patience. I still don't know about the existence of the powers $l$. But the rest is clear: If $\mathfrak{m}^l m=\{0\}$ for some $l>>0$ for any $m\in M$, then it is clearly also true for the generators of $M$ and so there is some $l>>0$ with $\mathfrak{m}^lM=0$. And this gives us a finite filtration: $0=\mathfrak{m}^l M\subseteq \mathfrak{m}^{l-1} M\subseteq .... \subseteq M$, so it lacks to show that this gives us a composition series. But this is done in another post. See:

Comment: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/570883/a-noetherian-module-annihilated-by-a-power-of-maximal-ideal-must-has-finite-leng

Comment: @Jules The ring $R/\text{Ann}_R(m)$ is local artinian, and hence the maximal ideal is nilpotent (in general, the nilpotents are the intersection of all prime ideals, but there's only the maximal ideal here). Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Since everything is noetherian, finite length is the same as artinian. You can also do the following: $\{\mathfrak m\}=\operatorname {Supp} M=V(\operatorname {Ann} M)$, hence the formal Nullstellensatz yields $\mathfrak m =\sqrt{\operatorname {Ann} M} $. Hence $R/\operatorname {Ann}M $ is artinian and thus $M$ is also artinian, since it is finitely generated over an artinian ring.

---

Note that the converse is also true. If a finitely generated module over a noetherian local ring is artinian, then it is supported on the maximal ideal. Indeed, say $M$ is generated by $n$ elements, then these give rise to an injection $R/\operatorname{Ann} M \hookrightarrow \bigoplus_{i=1}^n M$. Thus $R/\operatorname{Ann} M$ is artinian, hence zero-dimensional. Hence the only prime ideal of $R/\operatorname{Ann} M$ is $\mathfrak m$, i.e. $\operatorname {Supp} M=V(\operatorname {Ann} M)=\{\mathfrak m\}$